# How can I sort query result of play morphia with multi field?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

I want to query item from mongoDB using morphia, but I found the order method has only one parameter, can I query data with multi order field like:

List items = Item.q().order("-updateTime").order("-createTime");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just separate the fields with commas.  The wiki has examples:  https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#sort

Comment: Please don't post links without an explanation. The link posted has moved and the same information is not available at the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> List items = Item.q().order("-updateTime,createTime,otherField").asList();